# run beanstalkd job put from php tube to fivebeans worker

Tags: php, node.js, queue, jobs, beanstalkd

Hi have an php app in which i put some job via https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk/

```
$pheanstalk
            ->useTube('testtube')
            ->put(json_encode(array('hello' => 'mdjaman')));
```

then i want to use nodejs https://www.npmjs.com/package/fivebeans worker to process the job; unfornatedly i missed something in the great documentation of fivebeans
Can someone point me to right track. Here my js file

```
var Beanworker = require('fivebeans').worker;
var options =
{
    id: 'worker_4',
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 13000,
    handlers:
    {
        type: 'emitkeys'
    },
    ignoreDefault: true
}
var worker = new Beanworker(options);
worker.start(['testtube']);
worker.on('info', function(message) {
    console.log('worker started with msg ' + message);
});
```

Comment: Although I didn't vote on this question, I will mark it as 'Should Be Improved'. I think both your problem and your question needs to be clarified. This post doesn't conform properly to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DanBeaulieu improve sure i would but tell me what you did not understand?

Comment: Your not saying what your program is currently doing. Is it crashing? Is it throwing an exception? If so mention it.

Comment: my main program is in php in which i passed a payload for a working queue to fire some job in nodejs. Im looking for help from guy you used or understand fivebeans because i don't know how to proceed

Comment: and my program does nothing coz i don't know how to proceed job from tube with the fivebeans

Comment: @DanBeaulieu do you have experience with beanstalkd job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

End up using another implementation [nodestalker](https://github.com/pascalopitz/nodestalker)

Answer (score 1):

- Saying "It Doesn't Work" - doesn't help.
- Beanstalkd is usually started on port 11300, not 13000

Comment: Worth say that the host and the port are because my app run on vagrant box and pupphet provision. And again have no problem putting job to beanstalk tube, everything works at this point. The problem is want to process job with nodejs https://www.npmjs.com/package/fivebeans

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
$tt["payload"] = array('hello' => 'mdjaman');
$tt ["type"]="testtube";      
$js = json_encode($tt);
$tid = $beans->useTube('testtube')->put($js);
```